# Array of ArratList<Integer> - add error

Tags: java, arrays, reference, arraylist, addition

I have one Array of ArrayList with this initialization:

```
distMemoria = new ArrayList[cantCepas];
for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayPasador = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> distancia = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    distMemoria[sortedList.get(i)-1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    distancia = distancia(sortedList.get(i), mutaciones, arrayPasador);         
    distMemoria[sortedList.get(i)-1] = distancia;
}
```

But for every iteration of the for I have the result of "distance" in all the positions.
For example in the first iteration distancia gave me "[2]" and, in the second "[2, 5]". But when I save this result in distMemoria[sortedList.get(i)-1], both positions are updated to [2,5].

What's going on? I am missing some reference?

Comment: What type is `distMemoria`?

Comment: static ArrayList<Integer>[] distMemoria; (is global).

Comment: Please explain better what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm saving the results of the function "distance" (ArrayList <Integer>) in one array (distMemoria []) but distMemoria [sortedList.get (i) -1] = distance; updates all the variables that have already been initialized.

Comment: This Question is not intelligible.  Please turn it into a SSCCE that actually demonstrates what is happening.  Be sure to include the `distancia` method, because that could be where the actual problem is.

Comment: not sure what is going on. but generally you would not declare a array list/ array inside a loop, as it will be redeclared for every iteration and the old one lost (unless you save it in some other variable -> but even then unless there is an inner loop -> why are you declaring in the loop? need to better explain what you want to do and what the other methods are. also are the lists of the same size? your using list a size to get from list B ?